# SwiftMailer Throttler plugin - how many emails per minute do you recommend

Tags: email, smtp, swiftmailer, throttling

I have SwiftMailer app that is sending around 13,000 emails overnight - I just wondered what you guys reckon is the ideal setting for the Throttler Plugin?

Would 200 emails per minute be ok?

Comment: Ask your smtp server's admin what an acceptable rate is. Anything else is "who knows". I'll go out on a limb and say that 50 kajillion mails per second is too high.

Comment: I will check with our admin when the back in - he should know, I just thought that they might be a generic value most people use. thanks tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you delivering directly or using a smarthost?
Did you check your provider's general terms and conditions for some volume-restriction of SMTP?

Comment: It is via SMTP - I will need to consult our admin & see what they recommend.